# Jsch: HTTPS over tunnel

Tags: ssh, https, jsch

I can establish a port forwarding session in Ubuntu as follows:

`ssh -L 8000:dev.mycompany.com:443 jump.mycompany.com`

now I'd like to emulate this with Jsch:

```
    public static void openTunnel() {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    String privateKey = "~/.ssh/id_rsa";
    try {
        jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
        log.info("Connecting to {}@{}", getJumpUser(), getJumpServer());
        Session session = jsch.getSession(getJumpUser(), getJumpServer(), 22);
        session.connect();
        session.setPortForwardingL(8000, getHost(), 433);
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        log.error("", e);
    }
}
```

However I get the following exception after the tunnel is set up, and trying to connect to it with RestTemplate (Spring HTTP Client - but curl gives an error as well):

```
ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)
```

What do I have to confiugre in Jsch so that it does exactly the same as the openssh client?

Comment: You could check `/var/log/auth` on the server, probably there is a hint

Comment: Do you keep the session open? Isn't it garbage collected?

Comment: so the session seems to be setup but when I'm trying to open an https connection with a client (from java or curl), I get that handshake error. I don't get such an error when setting up the tunnel with the ssh command.

Comment: Is that an answer to my question? I do not follow.

Comment: I can't believe, that your `curl https://localhost:8000` works with `ssh` , it should throw something like `curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'`

Comment: adding “—insecure”. this is not the problem. also the java client is skipping cert check.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose, you're trying to get a connection to a https webserver that's not public available.

The port forwarding works, BUT https will not work on localhost:8000, because the certificate is for `dev.mycompany.com` and not `localhost`.

You can cheat, by adding an entry into your `hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1 dev.mycompany.com
```

But probably it's easier to try socks5.

```
ssh jump.mycompany.com -D 8005
```

And then setting in your browser (sample for firefox):

> Select: Manual proxy configuration:
>   Socks Host: localhost
>   Port: 8005
>   Socks5

Comment: setting up a tunnel with ssh in ubuntu and then using https://localhost:8000 works but jsch tunnel doesn't, so it's not the cert. thanks for the socks hint, this is an integration test with junit on a build server (bitbucket pipelines).